# Black screen with Solid Underscore in top left corner of screen Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server

Tags: drivers, display, amd-graphics

I have a Dell PowerEdge 1950 1U server, and I have been using Ubuntu for quite some time now. A couple of months ago, I noticed that the monitor that's connected to the server no longer displayed a login screen or anything other than a solid underscore in the top left of the screen.

It does display properly up until Ubuntu gets to the part where I'm supposed to login to the command prompt. I have tried using nomodeset in order to get to the command prompt, however, I am unsure which Graphics Drivers I am required to use.

Dell's website offers drivers for RedHat Enterprise Linux and CentOS however no options for Ubuntu users, and my server is years out of its support from Dell.

When I ran `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` it showed up with `0e:0d.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 [1002:515e] (rev 02)`

I am completely unsure of what I should do to get my server to boot up. I do have the proprietary AMD drivers installed, which I installed trying to get my server to display on the monitor. But that didn't work.

The ones I installed were `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` and `mesa-vdpau-drivers`.

I am entirely unsure what I should install to get the proper drivers or whether I should downgrade from the latest Ubuntu version and try that. However, I would really prefer to fix this without having to completely reinstall, because of the amount of data I have on this server, it would take me hours to back everything up for a reinstall.

The server does not have any form of Secure Boot options in its BIOS and it is installed through legacy BIOS since the server doesn't support UEFI.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Edit: I have tried the steps listed in [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), I have Googled this and followed this issue for about a month now trying solutions when I have free time. Nothing has worked, all it does is after doing nomodeset or installing drivers, it will boot into said black screen right after it sets the hostname, even with nomodeset turned on. I can, however, SSH just fine into the server.

Booting into it with no splash it is failing on `Feb 19 10:35:30 awd kernel: i5k_amb i5k_amb.0: hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().`

My server isn't UFEI or emulating UEFI and it isn't BIOS emulating UEFI. It is simply a legacy BIOS. So those solutions won't help me.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I have already tried the solutions listed there, none of them have helped me in any way. Also, my machine is BIOS not UEFI and I get no error messages in the system log when checking the boot logs from SSH.

Comment: Nomodeset didn't work, all it did was lower the resolution and make the boot slower cause of the messages being lower resolution, as soon as it got to the set hostname to awd part it went black.

Comment: The fact that the duplicate target's solutions don't work for you does not mean that your question is not a duplicate. Feel free to get enough rep to put a bounty on the dupe target.

Comment: The fact that you can `ssh` and even login locally after pressing ALT+something shows that the server is booting up. The problem is it does not show the login prompt on the local screen.

Comment: I have it set to quiet splash in the grub options. What is the default setting for this?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu Server, but `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` confuses me as Xorg isn't used by Ubuntu Server (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-server) as Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI.  I have a couple of the servers you mention, and I don't think they meet the graphic requirements for Ubuntu Desktop, so I wonder if you've converted your server system into a desktop system.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to boot me into the command prompt by using Alt + ← and it let me login perfectly fine. Would be nice for somebody to comment and tell me how to get into this on startup without having to do this each time.